# I have a bunch of kubernetes stuff in my local Docker desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How do I get rid of them? Docker doesn't think they exist and my kubernetes-fu isn't good enough yet.

[image]

Comment: This will delete all unused images `docker rmi $(docker images | awk '{ print $3 }')`

Comment: No, the containers are running and I get loads of image being used messages.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove them while they are in use. You'll have to shut down the Kubernetes system first, that's under Preferences (the gear icon) and then Kubernetes. Once that is done, run `docker system prune` to clean up unused everything.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't shut them down from the docker desktop and I don't have enough knowledge of kubectl.

Comment: You have to entirely disable the Kubernetes that runs inside Docker Desktop.

Comment: And you can't remove them with kubectl either. Those images are the Kubernetes control plane.

Comment: Stopping k8s and `docker prune` did nothing.

k8s control plane means nothing to me. Simple words please.

Stopping k8s, I could delete the images fine, restarting and the images all reappear.